# Как запихнуть несколько функций с разными параметрами в массив CoffeeScript?

Tags: массивы, coffeescript, хеширование

Есть хеш:

```
config.services = {
  auth:      'http://localhost:3200'
  user:      'http://localhost:3201'
  title:     'http://localhost:3202'
  admin:     'http://localhost:3203'
  rule:      'http://localhost:3204'
  analytics: 'http://localhost:3205'
  commerce:  'http://localhost:3206'
  datum:     'http://localhost:3207'
}
```

И есть цикл:

```
functions = for key, value of config.services
  (callback) ->
    http.get "#{value}/ping", (response) ->
      callback(response.statusCode != 200, [ "#{key}_service", response.statusCode ])
```

Нужно чтобы после этой операции в массиве лежали функции с разными параметрами из хеша, но в результате, везде только последняя запись из хеша.

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Прочитав название вопроса и увидев тег "javascript", не могу не вспомнить http://habrahabr.ru/post/195944/

Comment: Добавил такой тег только потому что нету тега "CoffeeScript"

Comment: Теперь есть :)

Comment: Жуть, а не код. Особенно скобок нет.

Answer (score 1):

После проб и ошибок я нашел ответ на официальном сайте [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org)
вот как теперь выглядит мой код:

```
pings = for service, url of config.services
  do (service, url) ->
    (callback) ->
      http.get "#{url}/ping", (response) ->
        callback(response.statusCode != 200, [ "#{service}_service", response.statusCode ])
```

Ну и [ссылка](http://rzrsharp.net/2011/06/27/what-does-coffeescripts-do-do.html) почему же такое происходит, и как с этим бороться :)
Всем удачного кодинга